# How far is public-key crypto involved in "banking world"?

Tags: public-key, signature, authentication, smartcard

I would like to know how public key cryptography is used in the banking world. I am not looking for big details, but for example:

- Are banking card embedding a private key used for signing (authenticating) user transactions?
- During a transaction between Bank A and Bank B, is Bank A expected to sign the transaction so that it can't deny the transaction?
- How are digital signatures used between a Point-Of-Sale and a Bank?

Comment: There are whole books talking about the things you´re asking. Therefore, it´s a bit too broad to answer in the limited scope a Q&A site can offer. As for ideas to edit your question: describe what research have you done, what you learned from that, and where you´ve hit a specific problem that we can help you with. In case of doubt, take a look at the hints provided at [“How to ask.”](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: As to your first bullet: yes, see [EMV 4.3](http://www.emvco.com/specifications.aspx?id=223)

Comment: I'm not sure this question is to broad; it has some specific answers. - 1. yes; EMV for example uses RSA, in the usual indirect way via an symmetric key. - 2. Yes, but that is rarely done for single transactions; among themselves, banks usually sign transaction bulks. 3. No; POS and Bank are not directly connected, so not at all. There are payment providers between Bank and POS, who usually do two-way authentication with the(ir) devices before perfoming transactions.